# How to sort a column of data frame based on the index of the original data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

This may be very simple to achieve, but has me stumped.

I have a data frame:

```
    chip1 chip2
P1  1.57  2.13
P2  2.04  1.92
P3  1.90  2.11
P4  1.48  2.24
```

The next step for quantile normalization is to sort each column and then generate the row wise mean, like this:

```
   chip1 chip2     M
P1  1.48  1.92 1.700
P2  1.57  2.11 1.840
P3  1.90  2.13 2.015
P4  2.04  2.24 2.140
```

Then the final normalized data is:

```
       chip1  chip2
   P1  1.840  2.015
   P2  2.140  1.700
   P3  2.015  1.840
   P4  1.700  2.140
```

The normalized data is generated using the M column of the previous data frame which is reordered based on chip1 and chip2 from the first data frame. How can I order the M column using the index from the original columns? I'm little lost?

Thank you.

Comment: looks like your first data frame is in the same order as the second?

Comment: My bad :). I must have mistakenly copied the other one. I apologize for not rechecking my post. It's updated. Thank you @BrodieG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nrm <- rowMeans(sapply(df, sort))
sapply(df, function(x) nrm[rank(x)])
```

produces:

```
     chip1 chip2
[1,] 1.840 2.015
[2,] 2.140 1.700
[3,] 2.015 1.840
[4,] 1.700 2.140
```

Comment: If I wanted to be picky I'd also suggest doing `data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) nrm[rank(x)]))` so the coercion to a matrix doesn't occur.

Comment: @thelatemail, but you'd never want to be picky, would you ;).  BTW, `df` is also apparently a base/stats function.  Does that drive you crazy?  I think I'm too used to using that as a variable name to stop now.

Comment: Haha... picked up one, missed one! I'll turn the cat o' nine tails on myself shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have mentioned, I wish it is what you mean.

```
> X = cbind(rnorm(5, 1), rnorm(5,0))
> X
          [,1]         [,2]
[1,] 2.2629543 -1.539950042
[2,] 0.6737666 -0.928567035
[3,] 2.3297993 -0.294720447
[4,] 2.2724293 -0.005767173
[5,] 1.4146414  2.404653389
> Y = apply(X,2,sort)
> cbind(Y, rowSums(Y))
          [,1]         [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.6737666 -1.539950042 -0.8661834
[2,] 1.4146414 -0.928567035  0.4860744
[3,] 2.2629543 -0.294720447  1.9682338
[4,] 2.2724293 -0.005767173  2.2666621
[5,] 2.3297993  2.404653389  4.7344527
> X[order(rowSums(Y)),]
          [,1]         [,2]
[1,] 2.2629543 -1.539950042
[2,] 0.6737666 -0.928567035
[3,] 2.3297993 -0.294720447
[4,] 2.2724293 -0.005767173
[5,] 1.4146414  2.404653389
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but that's not what I'm looking for. Here's the algorithm for the Quantile Normalization.

Given n vectors of length p, form X, of dimension p × n, where each
array is a column.
Sort each column of X separately to give Xs.
Take the mean, across rows, of Xs and create X's, an array of the same dimension as X, but where all values in each row are equal to the row means of Xs.
Get Xn by rearranging each column of X's to have the same ordering as the corresponding input vector.